# Can a AMS1117 fixed voltage regulator be used in a reverse biased way?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, reverse-bias

I was looking at a breadboard power module ([link](https://www.banggood.com/MB102-2-Channel-3_3V-5V-Breadboard-Power-Supply-Module-White-Breadboard-Dedicated-Power-Module-MB-102-Solderless-Bread-Board-p-1524894.html)). This board has two inputs: a DC plug (7-12V advised) and a USB mini (5V). Using either of those two inputs, the board provides two voltages (3.3V and 5V) using fixed AMS1117 voltage regulators. So far, so good.

However, looking at the module, and after some path testing with a multimeter, it seems that something strange is happening. When using the USB as input to power the module, the 3V3 regulator gets its input through the 5V regulator. But in a strange reversed way. (The voltage at the input pins of both AMS1117's is around 4.5V.)

The schematic of the board is this (excluding the output headers and switches):
[image: Schematic of the power supply module]

Using either DC or USB as input power, both 5V and 3V3 rails are working. But I suspect that the 3V3 rail using USB as input power, might not be a proper supply.

Am I correct in assuming that this reversed use of the 5V regulator to power the 3V3 regulator is less than desirable? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Seems normal. You are experiencing the body diode or protection diode built into the linear regulator.

Comment: Yes that would explain the slight voltage drop (5v -> 4.5V), but all power drawn from the 3V3 rail, should now pass in reverse through the 5V regulator. Is that ok?

Comment: Yes that is OK, see the datasheet, page 4 section "Protection diodes". *Diodes between the input and output are not usually needed.
Microsecond surge currents of 50A to 100A can be handled by the
internal diode between the input and output pins of the device* That sounds like an ESD protection diode which can also handle the currents you're using.

Comment: No, it's not OK. Usually you would need a path controller, jumper or switch. You can't supply from two sources in that simplificated way.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I mean when only using USB as input. (Using DC and USB at the same time would create a problem I imagine.)

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie So it is possible and the AMS IC might be ok, but it is not the best way to do this?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič You can, I agree it isn't a preferred or "neat" solution but it does work and as long as the currents stay within reasonable limits, this will last. Not every design needs to be "military grade".

Comment: "The best way" depends on what is best. For a cheap module like this it is all you need. A proper switching circuit with MOSFETs and whatnot would be overkill and make the module more expensive. Would I design like this for a critical system in an aircraft? **Nope**. Is it good enough for a hobby and experiments module: Yes.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Very true. I was just wondering. Thanks

Comment: You might want to put a Schottky diode in there, since some regulators are stressed by too much reverse current.  A Schottky will also have a lower voltage drop.  Also, I think you have your regulators switched above.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis You're right I switched the two..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an internal "feature" of an IC for an unintended purpose may always work, or sometimes work, or stop working in un-understood circumstances.

In this case, adding a Schottky diode across the regulator from Vout to Vin to take the 'reverse' current would be an effective, cheap and sensible solution.

TI & Nat Semi datasheets contain references to an internal protection diode.
A sample Asian datasheet did not. They still MAY exist.

[TI datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf)
Section 7.4 page 12. Figure 13

[Natsemi data sheet page 10 fig 4](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf)

Both say:

Under normal operation, the LM1117 regulators do not need any protection diode. With the adjustable device, the internal resistance between the adjust and output terminals limits the current. No diode is needed to divert the current around the regulator  even  with  capacitor  on  the  adjust  terminal.  The adjust pin can take a transient signal of±25V with respect to the output voltage without damaging the device.

When a output capacitor is connected to a regulator and the input is shorted to ground, the output capacitor will discharge into  the  output  of  the  regulator. The  discharge  current  de-pends on the value of the capacitor, the output voltage of the regulator, and rate of decrease of VIN. In the LM1117 regulators, the internal diode between the output and input pins can  withstand  microsecond  surge  currents  of  10A to  20A.

**With  an  extremely  large  output  capacitor  (≥1000  μF),  and with input instantaneously shorted to ground, the regulator could be damaged.In this case, an external diode is recommended between the output and input pins to protect the regulator, as shown in Fig 4 (13)**